# How to export data with multiple worksheet Yii2 ExportMenu

Tags: php, yii2, export, yii2-advanced-app

There is an easy way to create multiple worksheets in one exported excel file using `Yii2 kartik ExportMenu`. Its working for single tab, but now I want to export data in multiple tabs in single sheet of `csv` and `excel`.
Is this possible or I need to use `PHPExcel` directly for this?

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'columns' => $gridColumns,
     'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
     'dropdownOptions' => [
      'label' => 'Export',
      'class' => 'btn btn-warning', 
      'export' => true,
      'toolbar'=>[
      '{export}',
      '{toggleData}'
      ]          
    ],
     'exportConfig'=>[
     ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML=>false,
     ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT=>false,
     ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF=>false,
     ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL=>false,
     ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension has been built to only export data displayed on the client.
You need to write your own query/code for exporting large data sets.

An alternative is to use the [yii2-export](http://demos.krajee.com/export) extension which uses PHP Excel library to export and directly reads data from dataProvider.

But exporting very large data-sets typically are done faster via direct queries rather than too much processing done to change to other formats.